# Favicon not showing up on one of my pages in my website, but it works on all others

Tags: html

I'm getting no error warnings or anything like that when I was testing my site, but for whatever reason the favicon I designed for my site isn' working on one of my webpages despite the fact that I copied and pasted the html tag `<link rel="icon" href="pixil-frame-1.png" type="image/x-icon" />`from the working webpages to the webpage that isn't working.

Perhaps it's because the webpage it isn't working on is rather larger than the other webpages, but I'm not certain.  I already tried deleting my cache and history, but that doesn't seem to help.  As far as I know I don't think I changed any weird chrome settings or anything like that. The same thing happens on the version that's hosted on the internet.  I'd rather like to get this working just since it's been driving me crazy for the last few hours.

Answer (score 0):

`type="image/x-icon"` is for .ico format. For a png file use `type="image/png"`